# QR code printed with wrong url. .htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The issue is our marketing department printed the wrong QR code and the url www.batesvr.com\longcreek. Notice the . QRcode reader browser does not autocorrect the \ to a /. Is there a way in my .htaccess file to correct this issue so we don't have to reprint?

Comment: No, if the browser doesn't do it automatically for you then the visitor won't even be able to connect to your website so you can't issue a redirect on your end.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's worth trying to fix this rather than reprinting everything.

You can fix the '.' issue using the following `.htaccess` redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on

//301 Redirect
Redirect 301 /longcreek. /longcreek
```

Try adding this rule and check the URL. Depending on a device/browser backward-slash might be replaced with a forward-slash automatically. If not, it might be worth trying adding another redirect rule as well.

At the moment [www.batesvr.com](http://www.batesvr.com) seems to be down (500 error), so if it's your real website, you might route all the traffic to the actual page. It would be a hack, but might do the trick for now.

Let me know what worked and what didn't.